# Laravel 5.8 Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm, migration

---

**Objective**: Changing columns in MySQL with laravel migration, however raises the error below

> To change columns in mysql tables using migration requires the installation of the 'doctrine / dbal' dependency. Read the documentation on the link beside [https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns][1]

**Wrong choice for laravel 5.8**: `$ composer require doctrine/dbal`

**Problem**:

```
    $ php artisan migrate
         Migrating: 2021_01_14_031415_my_chage_migrate
```

---

```
   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found    
  at ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection.php:65
    61|      * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver
    62|      */
    63|     protected function getDoctrineDriver()
    64|     {
  > 65|         return new DoctrineDriver;
    66|     }
    67|
    68|     /**
    69|      * Bind values to their parameters in the given statement.

  Exception trace:
```

---

Comment: Hi Andre, have you run a `composer install` on your project. Can you add the composer.json code to your question AND the migration file please

Answer (score 4):

***Solution:***

1. `$ composer remove doctrine/dbal`
2. `$ composer require doctrine/dbal:2.*`

I hope it helps someone, good luck
;)

Comment: same issue on laravel 7.30.4 with doctrine/dbal (2.13.0) and it doesn't solve for me

Answer (score 1):

dotring/dbal 2.12.1 is the last stable version;

```
1.composer require doctrine/dbal:2.12.1

2.composer update
```